# Gnuplot x axis on top of the graph

Tags: gnuplot

How do I get gnuplot to draw the X axis (with the measurements etc) on the top of my graph rather than on the bottom ?

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick (or some variant thereof):

```
set xtics format ""
set x2tics
plot sin(x) axes x2y1
```

Gnuplot has x1 (bottom, default), x2 (top), y1 (left,default) and y2 (right) axes.  You need to pair two axes together in the `plot ... axes <axes>` specifier -- x first then y.  You can set the ranges too:  `set x2range [-30:30]`, the label (`set x2label "foo"`) although this looks a lot like a second title...  Basically `set x...` maps to `set x2...`.